# Smoothing data without losing the most recent elements

Tags: algorithm, smoothing

I'm currently trying to implement the Savitzky-Golay algorithm to smooth noisy data. This algorithm smooths each element by taking `m` adjacent elements, which means the last `m` elements are lost. The most recent elements are very important for my application so I would like to keep them.

Is there a way to adjust the algorithm to not lose the most recent elements? Or is there another good smoothing algorithm which does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several techniques to handle the end points. A few are covered [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter#Treatment_of_first_and_last_points). In summary, they are:

1. Extrapolating from closest points
2. Use a polynomial fitting to compute them
3. Compute convolution coefficients specific to the end points by using just the available end points on that side.